# Android Navigation component multiple backstack NavDeepLinkBuilder

Tags: android, navigation, deep-linking

I have problem with using NavDeepLinkBuilder in my case. My navigation graph looks like this:

1. HomeFragment (start destination of main graph)
2. Nested Graph: FragmentA (start destination of nested graph) -> FragmentB

HomeFragment and NestedGraph can be accessed using NavigationView (setup by NavigationUI):

```
 public fun setupWithNavController(
    navigationView: NavigationView,
    navController: NavController
)
```

And HomeFragment and NestedGraph are set as TopLevelDestinations. And it works without problem, so when I'm in FragmentA or HomeFragment I can open drawer, and when I'm in FragmentB I'm not able to open drawer, but I have to go back to FragmentA and then I can open drawer.

But when I try to use NavDeepLinkBuilder to navigate from Notification to FragmentB here comes the problem. I build PendingIntent like this:

```
 NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
    .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_main)
    .setDestination(R.id.fragmentB)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

And now navigating to FragmentB works fine. But on back button I'm coming back to FragmentA (and it's expected behavior) but when I'm opening DrawerMenu and try to go to HomeFragment I cannot do this. After debugging I discovered that it's caused by Navigation component thinking that I'm in HomeFragment backstack. Which is true (as when I click back button then I'm navigating to HomeFragment). Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks!